# make OpenCV in CentOS(Linux)

Tags: opencv

I try to install openCV 3.1.0 following this tutorial
http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html#gsc.tab=0

I cmake it with this command:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/path/to/install   /home/path/to/source
```

which could work. And then I just make, following errors appear:

```
Building CXX object modules/imgcodecs/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgcodecs.dir/src/grfmt_tiff.cpp.o
opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_tiff.cpp:61:18: error: tiff.h: No such file or directory

opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_tiff.cpp:62:20: error: tiffio.h: No such file or directory

opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_tiff.cpp: In constructor ‘cv::TiffDecoder::TiffDecoder()’:
```

Following many similar errors, anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: Check the output of CMake. Does it indicate to have not found some tiff library?

Comment: Either set `OPENCV_BUILD_3RDPARTY_LIBS` (or the individual `BUILD_TIFF`, etc. settings) to build and use the copies included in the opencv source. Otherwise install development packages for all the appropriate 3rd party libs.

Comment: Thanks, it's true I lost a libarary(ffmpeg) in the 3rdparty_libs, thanks for your useful help